# Send images using sendgrid C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send images in mails, but I am not sure what's wrong with my code.
Here is my code:

```
string imgPath= Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/logo-img.png");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hi There! I am using sendgrid to send images");
sb.Append("<a href='someurl'><img src='cid:myImage.png> Login in</a>");

LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource(imgPath, "image/png");
lr.ContentId = "myImage";

AlternateView AV = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sb.ToString(), null, "image/png");
AV.LinkedResources.Add(lr);

var from = new EmailAddress("abc@bac.com");
var subject = "Hi There!";
var to = new EmailAddress("xyz@xyz.com");
var plainTextContent = "Hello";
var htmlContent = sb.ToString();

var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
msg.SetFrom(from, "abc");

var sendingResult = SendMail(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `LinkedResource` or `AlternateView` classes do, but they don't appear to be part of the Twilio SendGrid C# library.

There is an example in the library docs for [sending attachments](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#attachments), but it doesn't show how to address the content within the email. But it's close. The key is that you need to load the file you want to attach and transform it to base64, then use the `AddAttachment` method to add it as an inline attachment to your mail, passing the content ID (`cid`) that you can refer to in the body of the message. Something like:

```cs
string imgPath= Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/logo-img.png");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hi There! I am using sendgrid to send images");
sb.Append("<a href='someurl'><img src='cid:myImage'> Login in</a>");

var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var from = new EmailAddress("abc@bac.com");
var subject = "Hi There!";
var to = new EmailAddress("xyz@xyz.com");
var plainTextContent = "Hello";
var htmlContent = sb.ToString();

var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
msg.SetFrom(from, "abc");
msg.AddAttachment("logo-img.png", file, "image/png", "inline", "myImage");

var sendingResult = SendMail(msg);
```

In this updated code the important parts are loading the file as base64:

```cs
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

and attaching the file to the message:

```cs
msg.AddAttachment("logo-img.png", file, "image/png", "inline", "myImage");
```

The `AddAttachment` method takes 5 arguements: the filename, the base64 content of the file, the mime type, the content disposition (for referring to images in the HTML you should use "inline"), and the `cid`. Note also that the `cid` is the entire string you should use to refer to the image, so if the image `cid` is "myImage" then you should refer to it as `cid:myImage`, like:

```cs
sb.Append("<a href='someurl'><img src='cid:myImage'> Login in</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You put quote in wrong place:

```
sb.Append("<a href='someurl'><img src='cid:myImage.png'> Login in</a>");
```